# What is the best way to implement data binding with a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding

It doesn't seem like there is an obvious to implement databinding using jQuery or any other javascript framwork.  I'm wondering if anyone has implemented databinding using jQuery in the same vein as WPF databinding, or even your standard databinding scenario (fill a table with the results of this resource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to fit the bill: http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Microsoft has this in the works for .NET 4.0 as part of the ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 functionality.

There is a community technology preview for this on [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24645) that is compatible with .NET 3.5.

Looks very slick and WPF-life - allowing developers to leverage all that Silverlight/WPF knowledge about databinding and generalizing that to client side javascript databinding.

Comment: This is over a year old and I cant find any information if this functionality which was highly publicized made it into the 4.0 release?  Are MS's proposals to enhancements to jQuery core (templating and data linking) super-ceding this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

A powerfull library can be found at http://www.jqxb.altervista.org